# Run a code continuously in background in cocoa

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, cocoa

I've been using [Swift-Keylogger](https://github.com/SkrewEverything/Swift-Keylogger) as a command-line program.

I thought of making a UI for it as I have started mac development recently.

As it is a command-line program, the author used `RunLoop.current.run()` in-order to run the keylogger continuously.

Now the problem is I can't use `RunLoop.current.run()` because it blocks the UI.

I have looked into `GCD` and it only runs a piece of code. But I want to run it continuously. I saw some additional articles about running continuously but I found running code continuously after every 'n' specified time by using `Timer`.

So, how can I replace the `RunLoop.current.run()` which has same behaviour without blocking UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: 05/07/2018**

To start and stop the keylogger from the UI, check this issue from [GitHub](https://github.com/SkrewEverything/Swift-Keylogger/issues/14)

---

**UPDATE: 18/01/2018**

Some guy approached me with same requirement as yours. After some discussion and trial and error method, he found a solution.

**1)** Just comment out the `RunLoop.main.run()` line in the keylogger code.

**2)** Now disable the app sandbox. If you want to enable the app sandbox, then add this entitlement `com.apple.security.device.usb = YES`.

---

**Original: 18/03/2017**

I also searched for it a lot in the beginning when I'm writing my keylogger. After a day I gave up.

I use `Process` in swift to run the keylogger from my UI.

**The way I do is:**

Do the necessary modifications in keylogger source like the path of files/folders.

Compile the keylogger source.

Drag the keylogger to your project in your Xcode and check `copy if needed`.

The executable is in resources folder inside your `.app`.

Run the executable using `Process` class and `launch()` to start the executable/ your keylogger.

You should terminate the created process, otherwise the keylogger will be running in the background. To stop the keylogger, use `terminate()` on `Process` variable.

**Code:**

```
let pathToKeylogger = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/Keylogger" // path to keylogger executable
keylogger = Process() // You need to declare this variable at class-level because you need to have the variable later to terminate it.
keylogger.launchPath = pathToKeylogger
keylogger.launch()
```

*To Terminate:*

```
keylogger.terminate()
```

---

**Edit: 18/03/2017**

Try to quit your app normally i.e.,  either clicking quit in menu bar or in the dock instead of pressing stop button in Xcode. I think you are pressing stop in Xcode.

Comment: I have a small problem. I placed `keylogger.terminate()` in `applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification)` but it's never called. I have checked by placing print statement and keylogger is still in the background when I checked in terminal.